# How to detect mouse clicking in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want this program for when user click on something either in application or outside of that, make a screen shot and save it as jpeg to a folder

This is the code that I want put those option in it:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

Private Function TakeImage()
    Return TakeImage(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height)
End Function

   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = CType(TakeImage(), Image)
End Sub
End Class
```

by the way I'm beginner in VB.NET

Comment: Click on what within the application? 
Why not use the TakeImage method on the click_event for the object in question?

Comment: What I meant is when user click any place(it can be an icon on the desktop or a link in a browser and etc) not only inside the application

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a desktop application and that TakeImage(,,,) works.
In your form, add a button, double click it and just call TakeImage from there.
Then there is saving as jpeg - just google on how to convert the bitmap(?) format from TakeImage to jpeg and google how to save it. In VB.Net it should be rather easy to handle files.

But first set a return type on your TakeImage function. Probably like `as Image`. It doesn't change your program but is good practice and will aid you in your learning as the editor will continuously give you helping feedback.

Happy hacking!